# Pass jQuery key-value pair to a c# dictionary in controller action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have a key-value pair where I put items on a click event like this:

```
var product_ids = {};
$(document).on('click', '.chkItem', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        product_ids[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr("price");
    } else {
        delete product_ids[$(this).attr('id')];
    }
});
```

Through this I add ItemID value and item's price to the key-value pair.

Now I need to pass these values that I stored into my controller action. I did it like this:

```
$.post("/Controller/GetAllProducts", { ids: product_ids)},StartLoading())
    .done(function (data) {

    })
    .fail(function (data) {

     });
```

And this is my action:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetAllProducts(Dictionary<string,string> ids) {
    //trying now to access te values...
}
```

When I check contents of the ids dictionary I get following values:

```
{[controller, myControllerName]}

{[action, GetAllProducts]}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? :/

Comment: Use a model containing 2 properties (for `id` and `price`) and the parameter will be `IEnumerable<yourModel>` (but you will need to stringify the data and set the `contentType: 'application/json'` using the `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: Note that if `.attr('id')` is an `int`, then `Dictionary<int, string>` may work (the problem you have is that its binding to the `RouteValueDictionary` which contains keys for the controller and action name)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Okay trying ^_^

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay we're getting somewhere xD now it says it has 0 items inside haha...

Comment: Note it will be `var product_ids = [];` and in the loop - `product_ids .push({ id: x, price: y });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke and how do I then delete the item when the item is unchecked ? delete somethinsomethingsomething ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170534/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user987).

Comment: @IgnacioAra please do not make edit's that only change layout, there is no need for them when your edit has to be reviewed by three other people.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare the headers or data as form to take the data from post request at c#, also did you checkted your problem on which side. Try to handle your json object with console.log then check the incoming data from c#